# Ember: Poll an api every 5 secs, but after getting response of the previous call

Tags: javascript, ember.js, polling

On transition to a route, Make an api call, wait for the response and once you get a response, wait 5 secs and again call the same api and keep repeating this, until I exit out of the route.

So the catch here is to wait 5 secs, after getting the response, and again do the same api call.
How do i achieve this in ember?
I have tried polling as below, but polling doesn't suffice my requirement.

```
 Ember.Route.extend({  
  model: function() {
    var interval = 1000 * 60;
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.model().then(function(json) {
        this.controller.set('model', json);
      }.bind(this));
    }, interval);

    return Ember.$.getJSON('some api request');
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var interval = 1000 * 60;
    var five = function() {
      this.model().then(function(json) {
        this.controller.set('model', json);
        setTimeout(five, 5000);
      }.bind(this));
    };
    Ember.run.later(this, five, interval);
    return Ember.$.getJSON('some api request');
  },
```

Comment: Try `if (some_var) setTimeout(five, 5000);`

Comment: HI @Chris G, wont this cause 2 loops to run, one for ember.run.later and one for setTimeout ?

Comment: When you call later(), JS waits 60 seconds, then runs the function for the first time. At the end of the function, a new call is scheduled for 5 seconds from now, then the function ends. Should be one loop.

Comment: is setTimeout a good solution? cant we use ember.run.later itself?

Comment: Should work both ways, yes. My guess is that later() calls setTimeout.

Comment: Using `Ember.run.later` makes ember aware of the async behavior, which will make testing this feature much easier.